# Extra char(s) found in EDI.ISASegment

Tags: biztalk

When I was inbounding trading partner's X12 file using biztalk. I am required to store the ISA segment of the file in a db table.

I am using the promoted property EDI.ISA_Segment to get the ISA string.

Recently, I noticed for one trading partner. There're extra chars found in the ISA segment: 
 The ISA segment shall look like this:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*########       *ZZ*#####          *150105*0606*^*00501*000000936*1*P*>~
```

But the ISA_segment using the promoted property was:

```
    ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*########       *ZZ*#####          *150105*0606*^*00501*000000936*1*P*>~
G
```

There's extra < LF >+G in the ISA segment.

The trading partner do send the X12 file with segment suffix  and it was also configed in the BizTalk Agreement correctly.

It looks BizTalk takes 2 extra chars to the ISA_segment after reached the "~", I am wondering if this is a bug or it is caused some mis-configuation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the original EDI using a good text editor such as Notepad++ so you can see exactly what those characters are.

The X12 spec allows the use of CR and/or LF as part of the Segment Terminator so it might be a side effect of changing encodings from EDI to the database.

Comment: Thanks. John. NotePad++ is what I am using to see what the character is. And it is not happen in database side, cause I also output the ISASegment  to eventlog and it also have extra chars. But I will check to see if changing the charset from UTF-8/Unicode to Basic will help

Comment: It's probably not the database since the promoted property is off...  But this is on the right track, check the agreement settings and make sure you aren't tellling BizTalk to expect CR + LF when the trading partner is only using LF (after looking at the original message to see what characters are being included).